# Getting Manufacturer Vendor ID for ADB

Tags: android, vendor

Is there any "universal" vendor ID that I can use so that ADB can detect my China-made Tablet? I can't find the vendor ID of the manufacturer. When I look into Device Manager in Windows the  Vendor is a string and not a number. The device is a Cherry Mobile Fusion Bolt tablet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this tool if you are on a windows machine- `lsusb` [Link](http://download.cnet.com/lsusb/3000-2086_4-75449103.html)

If you are on a linux machine, you can run the `lsusb` command.

The tool is for windows platform. Run it while your tablet is connected through a USB. It may show your Vendor ID. If it does, you can try manually adding it to `[USER_DIRECTORY] / .android / adb_usb.ini`.

Answer (score 1):

The vendor ID of the device can not be modified without replacing the software on the device (read a new AOSP installation). To [use the Google driver](http://androidmtk.com/install-google-adb-driver-manually), the Vendor ID of the product needs to be known.

### Finding Vendor ID in Windows

1. Start Device Manager
2. In the Hardware tree, right-click the hardware entry for the device for which the Vendor ID is to be determined.

[image: Properties for item to be checked]

3. On the Details tab, set the property drop-down to be "Hardware Ids". The Vendor ID is the 4 character hexadecimal number following the letters `VID_`. In the case below, the Vendor ID is `18D1`:

[image]

The `PID_`, which follows, is the Product ID. It also has a 4-digit hexadecimal number.